# Running a VB.NET application without all 3rd party libaries present

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a VB.NET winforms application (4.0) that depends on a number of external 3rd party libraries/software (ie mapping, directx, etc).

Ideally I would like to run a computationally-intensive portion of the program on another machine without having the other libraries installed (due to licensing restraints).

Is it possible to have the VB .NET application ignore the 'Imports'/requirement for the other libraries?  Can I error handle it?

Comment: What happened when you tried it for yourself?

Comment: If you have the source code you could split that portion off into a separate class.

Comment: external libraries will needed only when you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the functionality that requires 3rd party libraries in to a separate assembly that you load using reflection only when it is configured to do so.  If all the access is done through interfaces defined on the main program then it will not require a direct reference to the "plugin" assembly.